# Price optimization algorithms

Tags: regression, nonlinear-regression, elasticity

I am working on an price optimization problem for a Real Estate company. Basically, we'd like to optimize their rental price to maximize revenue on their properties.

I have submarket level data such as rental price, occupancy rate, comparable units, operating expenses (fixed cost) in the market, etc.

So for a given set of prices p = {40....60}, the objective is to find the optimal price point i.e the point where marginal revenue => marginal cost.

The first answer on this question is one of way of doing it, however, I may not always have probability distribution and the relationship between price and predicted occupancy is non linear:

[image]

Simple Linear: `()=+×()` where  is a scaling constant. Implies that price and probability are linearly related.  [2](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/134735/what-is-a-good-model-for-revenue-managment-price-optimization-problem)

I have attempted to use log-log regression to calculate elasticities:

```
import statsmodels.formula.api as sm

mod = sm.ols(formula = 'np.log(Occupancy) ~ np.log(Rent) + np.log(Income) + np.log(unemp) + np.log(comparable)', data=df).fit()

mod.summary()
```

[image]

The regression above fits price and economic control variables on occupancy rates.

With R-Square of `0.94`, I am suspicious of this model and there is likely an endogeneity problem. What non-linear methods can I fit to find the optimal rental price. Open to any other ideas/suggestions as well.

Comment: I found following links: https://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/robust_regression.html https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51972637/nonlinear-regression-with-python-whats-a-simple-method-to-fit-this-data-bette https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39895369/how-to-run-non-linear-regression-in-python https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52930401/how-to-get-a-robust-nonlinear-regression-fit-using-scipy-optimize-least-squares https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52943720/how-to-do-exponential-nonlinear-regression-in-python regards,
shibamouli

Comment: You need to supply different information and a clearer focus before the question "I would like a non-linear model" can be answerable.  Little about this summary of a linear model can help anyone determine what, if anything, might be done.

Comment: @whuber got it. I have edited the question and added more details. I hope that helps clarify the ask.

Comment: Maybe you can get better help at our sister site:  https://or.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Little late, but are you familiar with machine learning methods? For non linear relationships you could try gradient boosting, or if you have enough data a neural net.

Id also try to include additional features to regress the demand curve. Cyclical features like month of the year or day of the week (just [make sure to properly encode](http://blog.davidkaleko.com/feature-engineering-cyclical-features.html)). Additional features could also include price of competitors, macroeconomic indicators, users info, among others.

You can find a good overall exposition of the ML framework for pricing [here](https://tryolabs.com/blog/price-optimization-machine-learning) For an introductory idea behind ML regressors yu can always check [statquest](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCtYLUTtgS3k1Fg4y5tAhLbw).

Hope you find it useful.

Regards!